# Synonym proposal [zookeeper] -> [apache-zookeeper]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

They have exactly the same description in the wiki and refer to the same project homepage. My proposal is to make [zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper) synonym of [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper). Similarly [kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka) is synonym of [apache-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka), so this would be consistent with that example.

[image: zookeeper]

My current reputation does not allow me to suggest tag synonyms.

Comment: I assume [tag:zookeeper] should be the master tag since it has more questions? A [search for `apache` in all tag synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=synonym&filter=all) suggests that there's no convention for whether the [tag:zookeeper] or [tag:apache-zookeeper] becomes the master tag.

Comment: @GordonGustafson no, the pig will be a pig unless [you say that it's Apache Pig.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226637/213575)

Comment: Sigh, with that logic [java] would refer to coffee. This is a *programming* Q&A site. No one thinks we're programming cloven mammals.

Comment: @CodyGray [\[citation needed\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617817/pig-epidemic-java-array)

Comment: BTW, funny that it was also a Java question.

Comment: Since this request was completed, can [Matt's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339950/3357935) be marked as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done.

[zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper) now maps to [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper). I've also merged the tags, so that all questions previously tagged as [zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper) are now tagged with [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper) instead.

Answer (score 8):

### Currently, there are not enough qualified users to vote on this synonym

In order to suggest a tag synonym, you have to do so from the tag synonym page of the tag you desire to be the master. For [apache-zookeeper that is here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-zookeeper/synonyms). The requirements for being able to suggest a synonym, or vote on establishing a synonym, is that you have at least 2,500 reputation *and* a minimum of 5 as a net answer score in the a tag (the total of the up votes minus the down votes on your answers in that tag).

It requires a net positive vote of 4 for a synonym to be adopted. For apache-zookeeper, there are a total of [7 users that have a net answer score of 5 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-zookeeper/topusers). However, **only two** of those have more than 2,500 reputation. Thus, there are not, currently, enough qualified voters for this synonym to become active.

There will eventually be enough voters to make this possible, but that is not the case at this time. Once there are enough voters, the eligible voters need to know that this issue exists. I would guess that the synonym page for tags is one of the least frequented places for users to visit. Thus, without being proactive in informing the eligible users that the proposal exists, it will probably be quite a while prior to it being adopted (baring action on the part of a moderator).

In order to get more eligible voters, you could add [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper) to some questions which are currently tagged [zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper). Once the synonym is approved, the fact that both tags are used on a question should end up being merged (I assume).

Note: Meeting the net 5 answer score requirement in just the proposed synonym tag is not sufficient to be qualified to vote. You must meet the net 5 answer score requirement in the proposed master tag. While it seems reasonable to me to permit people to vote who have a high enough net answer score in the tag that is being proposed as the synonym (i.e. the synonym, not the master), this is not the case. In my opinion, this is a flaw because it allows a one tag to usurp the meaning of another tag without the ability of the people active in the proposed synonym tag participating in the vote, until after the synonym has been adopted. This could be a problem when there are namespace collisions, or users are just not informed of the current meaning of the proposed synonym tag.

Comment: *"In order to get more eligible voters, you could add apache-zookeeper to some questions which are currently tagged zookeeper."* No, that's nonsense. What you should do is **get a moderator to do it**. They can merge at the same time. I agree this *shouldn't* require a moderator, but the tag synonym system is completely broken, and it *does* require a moderator. There are plenty of them that one of them can help us out here, without needing ugly hacks.